# Bringing back old Chrome JS Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I really don't like the last changes that were made to the Chrome developer console with the latest chrome update. Does anyone know if there is a way to get back the old  design? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfRfb.jpg)

I was switching between errors, infos and normal log tab really often and I don't like the new drop down menus at all.

Furthermore information that was logged properly to the information tab (with console.info) isn't displayed when I filter for Level "Info" after the update.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: i was exactly looking for this.  It is kind of difficult to find about this situation,  though.

Comment: This is really annoying change. Before I could just filter out debug messages and not have those annoying "Violations", now they are all over the place and I have a hard time finding my logs between them...

Comment: I opened a ticket with them. Not too happy with this recent "enhancement"
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/lr4o92GK8gg;context-place=forum/chrome

Answer (score 3):

You can express your concern on a thread in their [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/kH3FiDLlsFg). I too am quite disappointed with this change...